# Not able to configure JPA With Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I've developed a project with Spring and JDBC, Now I'm trying to configure my Spring application with JPA and I was following this tutorial. I'm getting error at `getObject()` under `geJpaTransactionManager` method. I have included all JAR's mentioned. Am I missing any thing here?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "net.jpa.spring")
public class AppConfig{

 @Bean
   public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
      LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("LOCAL_PERSISTENCE");
      return factoryBean;
   }

   @Bean
   public JpaTransactionManager geJpaTransactionManager() {
      JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
      transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(getEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject()); --> Getting error here
      return transactionManager;
   }

}
```

The error is

```
The method getObject() from the type AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean refers to the missing type EntityManagerFactory
```

Comment: show your pom file please

Comment: This is a Dynamic web project.

Comment: do you have a hibernate-core jar file ?

Comment: Yes. But, I need to use only JPA mappings

Comment: we would need to see that pom.xml

Answer (score 2):

I think you might not have imported hibernate-jpa. The Maven dependency is as follows for hibernate-jpa. That is why the compiler is not able to detect the EntityManagerFactory.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```